# EntityManager doesn't refresh the data after querying

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, hsqldb, entitymanager

My current project uses HSQLDB2.0 and JPA2.0 .

The scenario is: I query DB to get list of `contactDetails` of `person`. I delete single `contactInfo` at UI but do not save that data (<kbd>Cancel</kbd> the saving part).

I again do the same query, now the result list is 1 lesser than previous result coz I have deleted one contactInfo at UI. But that `contactInfo` is still available at DB if I cross check.

But if I include `entityManager.clear()` before start of the query, I get correct results every time.

I dont understand this behaviour. Could anyone make it clear for me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Rather than querying again, try this:

```
entityManager.refresh(person);
```

A more complete example:

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("...");
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();

Person p = (Person) em.find(Person.class, 1);
assertEquals(10, p.getContactDetails().size()); // let's pretend p has 10 contact details
p.getContactDetails().remove(0);
assertEquals(9, p.getContactDetails().size());

Person p2 = (Person) em.find(Person.class, 1);
assertTrue(p == p2); // We're in the same persistence context so p == p2
assertEquals(9, p.getContactDetails().size());

// In order to reload the actual patients from the database, refresh the entity
em.refresh(p);
assertTrue(p == p2);
assertEquals(10, p.getContactDetails().size());
assertEquals(10, p2.getContactDetails().size());

em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
factory.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of `clear()` is explained in its [javadoc:](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html)

> Clear the persistence context, causing all managed entities to become detached. **Changes made to entities that have not been flushed to the database will not be persisted.**

That is, removal of `contactInfo` is not persisted.

`ContactInfo` is not getting removed from the database because you remove the relationship between `ContactDetails` and `ContactInfo`, but not `ContactInfo` itself. If you want to remove it, you need either do it explicitly with `remove()` or specify `orphanRemoval = true` on the relationship.

Comment: Looks like he doesn't want it to be removed as he has cancelled the actual deletion, but he wonders why the next time he queries the DB that item is not put back into the collection.