# <s:action> doesn't load latest updates of a OneToMany List

Tags: java, jpa, struts2, struts

I'm using the `<s:action>` tag of struts for load a list of elements belonging to another object ( a `@OneToMany` relationship ) from database using JPA API.

The problem is that when I add new elements to this list, the `<s:action>` doesn't show these recent objects after a long time (kind of caché).

How can I get the most current list to show up?

Comment: Agree what Dave has said could be a case of cache and exposing your domain data at UI level means you are at risk of some unexpected behavior better separate it from view layer.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a browser caching issue: disallow caching on that page.

That aside, I really don't advocate the usage of `<s:action>` for this purpose. IMO the view layer should be as dumb as possible.

That kind of initialization work belongs in the action or one of its services, where it's easier to test, and doesn't suffer from this problem (or a couple other subtle gotchas, but they wouldn't come in to play in this use case, I think).

Comment: Thanks, but for learning purposes I think that this is kind of server caché because I deleted a row of data from my db and the results of <s:action> tag still showed the data deleted.I'm forgetting some parameter or configuration? (I tried with differents browsers and deleted the caché, also I see the results in the console of eclipse)

Comment: @DanielFlores Did you *try* clearing the browser cache or turning caching off? It's *possible* you have some data caching set up, but it's pretty sucky caching if it takes measurable time to update after a write.

Comment: Thanks, (persistence caching?) I solved this with em.refresh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295386/entitymanager-doesnt-refresh-the-data-after-querying after a long time :(